# filenotfoundException when using startNode.bat command

Tags: websphere

I am trying to restart my node by running StartNode.bat in cmd. But it is giving me the following error, 
**ADMU0111E: Program exiting with error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users{userid}\workspaces\was_profiles{profilename}\config\cells\localcell\nodes\localnode\servers\nodeagent\server.xml (The system cannot find the path specified.)** When I checked the above path, server.xml is present in the path **C:\Users{userid}\workspaces\was_profiles{profilename}\config\cells\localcell\nodes\localnode\servers\server1\server.xml**. I am not sure how to restart my node. Also, I am restarting the node, since I get ORA error invalid username/password issue while trying to test my datasource connection in IBM websphere. 
     Most of the posts suggest me to restart websphere server and nodeagent as well. Eventually, when I start the nodeagent, I get the above error. I tried to use syncNode command, but could not find the deployment manager host name, port details for my application.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have single server version installed, not network deployment. In that case you dont have node and deployment manager, but just single server.

You should use commands like:

- `startServer.bat server1` - to start the server
- `stopServer.bat server1` - to stop server